# How to fix 'ts error 2532' when pushing an element to a typegoose model object

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have two Typegoose models: List and Entry whereas a list has an array of Entry-references:

listModel.ts:

```
import { arrayProp, prop, Ref, Typegoose } from "typegoose";
import { Entry, EntryModel } from "./entryModel";

class List extends Typegoose {
    @prop({required: true, unique: true})
    public id?: string;

    @prop({required: true, validate: (value) => (value !== undefined && value !== null)})
    public title?: string;

    @arrayProp({items: Entry})
    public entries?: Array<Ref<Entry>>;

    @prop({default: false})
    public ratingEnabled?: boolean;

    @prop({default: false})
    public checkboxEnabled?: boolean;
}

const ListModel = new List().getModelForClass(List);

export default ListModel;
```

entryModel.ts:

```
import { arrayProp, InstanceType, ModelType, prop, Typegoose } from "typegoose";

export class Entry extends Typegoose {
    @prop({required: true, unique: true})
    public id?: string;

    @prop({required: true})
    public title?: string;

    @prop()
    public text?: string;

    @prop({required: true, min: 0})
    public order?: number;

    @prop({default: false})
    public isChecked?: boolean;

    @prop({default: false})
    public rating?: number;
}

const EntryModel = new Entry().getModelForClass(Entry);

export default EntryModel;
```

Now to store an element inside a list I've tried:

```
export async function storeNewEntryInList(listId: string, entry: any) {

    // Create new Entry
    const newEntry = new EntryModel(entry);
    newEntry.id = uniqid();
    await newEntry.save();

    // Store in list
    const list = await getList(listId);
    list.entries.push(newEntry);
    return newEntry.id;
}
```

But when I try it to build my project I get the following error message:

**src/database/mongo.ts:51:5 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.**

51     list.entries.push(newEntry);

Comment: What object is possibly undefined?  (there's usually some red squiggly lines under the offending item).  Is it `list` or `list.entries`? In either case you should check that those are defined before accessing them.  `if (!list || !list.entries) throw new Error("my world is crumbling"); list.entries.push(newEntry);`  If that doesn't meet your needs, please consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] so that others can reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Hi the red squiggly line is under "list.entries"

Comment: So in this: `public entries?: Array<Ref<Entry>>;` the question mark `?` means that `entries` might not be present on a `list`.  You'll have to check it before pushing stuff onto it.  How sure are you at runtime that `entries` will exist?  If you are certain, maybe it shouldn't be declared as optional.  If you're not sure, you'd better do a runtime check and handle the case of it missing (`if (!list.entries) list.entries=[]`)

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer - this helped me a lot!